# How will our November trip in Italy be affected by the quake in May, 2012?

Tags: italy, natural-disasters

We are flying into Venice, taking a train to Florence (via Bologna), side trip to Pisa and then flying out of Rome.

Other than heartfelt feelings for those who suffered, can we expect delays, hassles, or other inconveniences due to [the recent quake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Emilia_earthquake)?

Answer (score 7):

It seems that trains are already running normally (from [travelbite.co.uk](http://www.travelbite.co.uk/travel-news/2012/05/22/italy-earthquake-ravages-historic-region)):

> The Emilia Romagna tourist board has also confirmed that motorways,
>   offices and trains are running normally.

As for sightseeing, Venice, Florence, Pisa and Rome are left intact.

Answer (score 5):

I confirm what Mouviciel has already written. There have been minor damages in Venice and Padua, whereas Florence, Pisa and Rome did not suffer from the earthquake.

If you're not planning to go around by car, thus going through the most badly hit area, you will not encounter any inconvenience. However, let's keep our fingers crossed and let's consider the quake a thing of the past.